# How to run java code from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have some java class files that I would like to run from javascript. They take in a string and spit out a string. I am trying to figure out the best/easiest way to execute them the class files from javascript so I can get/use its response. So as far as I know now here are my options.

1. Javascript ajax request to php then maybe `exec()` the jar
2. Javascript ajax request to my class files re implemented as servlet
3. Rewriting the class files as javascript and call it a day

1 is not ideal because I don't avoid using php, if I can. 2 sucks cause I don't want to run Apache Tomcat. 3 sucks naturally.

Long story short, I wrote a beautiful implementation of A* in java and I want to use it in a game I wrote in js without rewriting it. What would you do?

Comment: If the code is not that complicated, I would probably just rewrite in javascript.

Comment: Could you implement it as a really simple CGI script? That's basically a command-line script which is passed the request info as environment variables. At worst, you could use a shell script as the wrapper rather than PHP.

Comment: You can create an A* implementation in javascript that'll likely be quicker than the round trip time it would take to make an ajax call. It's the most sensible option, in my opinion.

Comment: Yea so I guess the answer is to rewrite. Not terrible news, I probably knew that was the right thing to do. I actually want to look more into the shell script wrapper idea. That could work really nicely. I guess the question would be how to run the bash script from js.

Comment: Calling a bash script from JS, or rather from AJAX, is trivial - configure your web server to execute CGI, and put the script in the right place. When you go to that URL, or request it with AJAX, the script will be run with some standard environment variables. The reason I haven't written an answer is that I don't know what the script would look like to invoke Java and pass on those variables.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to run Java through Javascript completely independently without using HTML. However, it isn't impossible.

You will first need to convert your Java game (.JRE file) into an applet. To do that, you might take the `public static main` void and replace it with an `Applet` initialization ([how to use applets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2owQOOuRX60)). It might seem tedious, but when you actually do it, it won't be that difficult.

Then, using Javascript's HTML Document Object Model ([learn more](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)), you can easily do something like this:

```
document.write('<embed src="foo.class">');
```

Also, keep in mind that the `<applet>` tag is NOT supported in HTML5. Like shown above, you can use the `<embed>` tag or also the `<object>` tag.

Sincerely, PD.

Comment: Yeah, and then your page would only work with browsers that have a working, semi-current Java installed.  That is not as common as it used to be, partially because of the never ending security breaches that exploit Java.  I banned Java from all the computers I manage a couple years ago and have enjoyed not having to maintain it and having one less security thing to worry about.  Have found no sites that I want to use that I can't because of no Java.  Just sayin...

Comment: Well I mean if the question asker wishes to implement a Java-based game on to a website, then they have to, well, accept the security causes. Java is a simple and greate programming language that can also be very advanced when necessary. Most major browsers support Java applets, and they're quick and easy to use.

Comment: It isn't a Java-based game.  It's a browser game in HTML and Javascript that they happen to want to use some functionality they current have in Java.  The clean answer is to rewrite that functionality in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, one could do that.

Comment: There is a very big difference between choosing the software you're willing to run on your server, and the software you are obliging the user to run in their browser.

Comment: Yea I need html5 compatibility. Also its a html5 canvas based game already written so I'm not about to rewrite that for an Applet. I'd rather rewrite the A* in js then.

Comment: @ShawnVolpe For HTML5 compatibility, do **not** use the `applet` tag. `Applet` tags are **not** supported. (Use `embed` or `object`, as shown in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp)